# Inertia JS - Vite application, Quasar installed, Quasar iconset installed, but not working. Seems impossible to make it working

Tags: vite, inertiajs, quasar

In app.js:

```
import iconSet from 'quasar/icon-set/fontawesome-v6'
import '@quasar/extras/fontawesome-v6/fontawesome-v6.css'
```

and:

```
setup({el, app, props, plugin}) {
    return createApp({render: () => h(app, props)})
        .use(plugin)
        .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
        .use(PrimeVue)
        .use(Quasar,{iconSet: iconSet,})
        .mount(el);
},
```

In template:

```
<q-btn color="yellow" glossy text-color="black" push label="First" icon="fabAngular"/>
```

The icon prop is not woking, it writes the name of icon instead of rendering it.
Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have tried it with different icon sets, but neither seems working. Icons are not rendering, only their names is written out.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am using the "built-in" icons (I think material), I could not install other icon sets.